# UIButton action EXC_BAD_ACCESS ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton, automatic-ref-counting

I have a scrollview and am adding a views with image label and button to the scrollview. I am adding the actions to the button and everything looks fine when I run it but when I click on a button the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I am using ARC so not sure if that is causing issues but it shouldn't. It seems as it can't find my action like something was released from memory. Here is my code:

```
-(void)lvlSelected:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"Selected level pack");
}

/*
 DISPLPAYPACKS
 This will take the loaded level packs and display them in the scroll view for selection
 */

-(void)displayPacks{
    //Iterate thru the installed level packs and load some tiles they can select
    for (int i = 0; i < installedLevelPacks.count; i++){ 
        levelPack *curPack = [installedLevelPacks objectAtIndex:i];
        CGFloat x = i * 110; 
        //Add the view to contain the rest of our elements
        UIView *tileView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 100, 125)]; 
        //view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor]; 
        //Add a label to the bottom to hold the title
        UILabel *titleLbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, tileView.frame.origin.y+100, 100, 25)];
        titleLbl.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
        titleLbl.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:12];
        titleLbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
        titleLbl.text=curPack.title;
        //Add the preview image to the tile
        UIImageView *previewImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:curPack.previewImg]];
        previewImg.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
        //Add the button over the tile
        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 125);
        //Set the tag to the level ID so we can get the pack later
        [aButton setTag:i];
        [aButton setTitle:curPack.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(lvlSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [tileView addSubview:previewImg];
        [tileView addSubview:titleLbl];
        [tileView addSubview:aButton];
        [lvlScroller addSubview:tileView]; 
    }
    //Set the total size for the scrollable content
    lvlScroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(installedLevelPacks.count*110, 125); 
}
```

I really am missing something here, I have done this before but not with ARC so that's why I am stuck on that being the culprit.

NSZombie output states:
An Objective-C message was sent to a deallocated object (zombie) at address: 0x6b8d530.  ￼

Comment: tell me the name of the class and where the object of this class is created????

Comment: Inder this method is inside a UIViewController and the class name is LevelPackViewController. This is being created from another view when the user presses a button(start button).

Comment: If I add the components to the view instead of the UIScrollView it works fine except I obviously can't scroll thru the level packs. However clicking them doesn't return an error so it makes me think that the UIScrolView is being released and so is the reference to the button and target, idk.

Answer (score 1):

What object is `displayPacks` a method of?  Is that object retained after `displayPacks` returns?  Keep in mind that controls like `UIButton` do **not** retain their targets, so you need something else doing it.

Comment: displayPacks is a method of a UIViewController. I am using ARC and am assuming it is being retained after displayPacks returns. I wasn't aware that UIButton does NOT retain their targets, I have done similar things like this in the past just not using ARC. All I am trying to do is add an image,label, and button into the scrollview and have it respond to touch events to see which one the user selected.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured it out totally, but looks like the bottons are not retained for some reason. What I have done to prevent such problem is using a class property NSMutableArray* my_buttons to hold the temp buttons:

UIButton* aButton = [[UIButton alloc] init...];
...
[my_buttons addObject:aButton];

Of course if there will be only 1 button you can make it a class property. Anyway avoid using it as a local variable. But again, this is just some workaround and I don't really know how you suppose to "retain" a local variable in ARC environment.